# Showing error messages in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I think its a very easy thing. Suppose, I am in a view of a corresponding function of a controller. The function looks like :

```
class SomeController extends AppController{
public function action(){
.
.
.
if($this->request->is('post')){
   .
   .
   .
   if(some error appears)
      I want to get back to the "action" view with the data that was given to it before
   else
      continue processing
   .
   .
   .
}
populate $data and send it to the view "action";
}
```

I mean, I just want to get back to the specific view with the data whenever I want. I used `redirect(array('controller'=>'some','action'=>'action'))`, but it didn't work. And using `render()` doesn't take the $data. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing are so called [flash messages](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html#displaying-notifications-or-flash-messages), they can be displayed in your view to tell the user something, for example that a save operation failed or succeeded. You will need to load the Session component and helper in your application to use them. So in your Controller (or AppController if you want to use it application wide), add:

```php
public $components = array('Session');
public $helpers = array('Session');
```

Then in your controller set the flash message desired:

```php
if (!$this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {
    // The save failed, inform the user, stay on this action (keeping the data)
    $this->Session->setFlash('The save operation failed!');
} else {
    // The save succeeded, redirect the user back to the index action
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

Make sure to output the flash message in your view, by simply echo'ing:

```php
echo $this->Session->flash();
```

That should do what you're looking for.

Comment: You mean, when I set the flash message, the same page will be shown, with all the data given before to it ? But, here you are redirecting only when the operation("save()") succeeds, not when it fails. Why ?@Oldskool

Comment: When it succeeds, you don't need to stay on the page any longer, (Unless, the intent is to save multiple records in a row, in which a redirect would not be required). A redirect will break you out of the create record loop.

Comment: @alairock explained it pretty well. Usually, whenever a save operation succeeded, there is no need to stay on the add/edit page. Of course, this is just an example and you can alter the behavior any way you want.